# Java Trails example TimeClient errors

Tags: java

For some reason I get an error about  it cannot find symbol: class TimeClient

I copied this code from the java trails on oracle.com
Here is TimeClient.java:

```
import java.time.*; 

public interface TimeClient {
    void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second);
    void setDate(int day, int month, int year);
    void setDateAndTime(int day, int month, int year,
    int hour, int minute, int second); LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime();
}
```

Here is the SimpleTimeClient.java file:

```
package defaultmethods;

import java.time.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleTimeClient implements TimeClient {

    private LocalDateTime dateAndTime;

    public SimpleTimeClient() {
        dateAndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.from(dateAndTime);
        LocalTime timeToSet = LocalTime.of(hour, minute, second);
        dateAndTime = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, timeToSet);
    }

    public void setDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        LocalDate dateToSet = LocalDate.of(day, month, year);
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.from(dateAndTime);
        dateAndTime = LocalDateTime.of(dateToSet, currentTime);
    }

    public void setDateAndTime(int day, int month, int year,
          int hour, int minute, int second) {
        LocalDate dateToSet = LocalDate.of(day, month, year);
        LocalTime timeToSet = LocalTime.of(hour, minute, second); 
        dateAndTime = LocalDateTime.of(dateToSet, timeToSet);
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime() {
        return dateAndTime;
    } 

    public String toString() {
        return dateAndTime.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TimeClient myTimeClient = new SimpleTimeClient();
        System.out.println(myTimeClient.toString());
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
javac SimpleTimeClient.java
SimpleTimeClient.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public class SimpleTimeClient implements TimeClient {
                                         ^
  symbol: class TimeClient
SimpleTimeClient.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        TimeClient myTimeClient = new SimpleTimeClient();
        ^
  symbol:   class TimeClient
  location: class SimpleTimeClient
2 errors
```

I have the files in the same directory so why can it not find TimeClient.java? Is it something so simple that I am missing?

Comment: Did you import the interface? Your class is in a specific package but it seems your interface is in the default package.

Comment: If these two files are in the same directory, and the directory is *not* named `defaultmethods`, then remove the package declaration from one of your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what was suggested by Makoto solved the problem. The file was not in a directory named as the package (SimpleTimeClient.java).

Comment: Oh!  I'm happy my advice helped.  Good of you to also codify it in an answer.